# Are there any password managers for iPhone and Windows XP?

Tags: windows, passwords, sync, iphone

Can you recommend a password manager that syncs between an iPhone and (at least one, preferably several) Windows XP computers?  Being able to generate passwords would of course be a nice addition, but is not required.

Comment: Have checked http://superuser.com/questions/255/how-do-you-keep-track-of-all-your-passwords ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'll finally use [Keeper](http://www.callpod.com/products/keeper). It's a very decent free password manager that has a desktop counterpart ($15) for Macs and PCs.  A very nice touch is that the iPhone version can export/import all its data as a file on any FTP server, either encrypted or not.  A very handy backup...

Two slight issues with Keeper: the font used is not always perfectly legible (i, I, l, 0, O), and it does not generate passwords.  A good product nevertheless.

Comment: Where does Keeper store it's data file?

Comment: On the iPhone itself.

Answer (score 5):

Currently I use [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) on my PC, an free open-source software on Windows to manage passwords. The iPhone version of KeePass is not available yet, but it is in development.

An existing commercial product for the iPhone is Iliumsoft's [eWallet](http://www.iliumsoft.com/site/iphone/products_ewallet.php). It has some nice features like synchronization to a desktop PC version of the software. Besides usernames and passwords, you can also use it for storing other sensitive information.

Answer (score 3):

Wanting to upgrade my current three-password method (basic, secure, and super-secure), I spent this evening researching this very topic. I wanted something that worked well with Firefox on my PC and Safari on my iPhone. I ended up deciding that there wasn't a sufficiently good solution. Here are the candidates are here's why I don't like 'em:

KeePass: Highly-regarded open source password manager, works with Firefox. Doesn't yet have iPhone support. Supposedly will have iPhone app Real Soon Now.

eWallet: Seems good, but costs money on the iPhone and PC, plus no Firefox support.

SplashID: Seems good, but costs money on the iPhone and PC, plus no Firefox support.

1Password: Seems perfect, has a clever bookmarklet solution for auto-filling on the iPhone, but is Mac-only (and costs money).

LastPass: Seems great, almost perfect, but stores your passwords on their server. Also seems to have cool bookmarklet feature, but this only works on the Mac. Came closest to persuading me.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but in looking for a password manager for iPhone and PC it came up at the top of the list. And for us as users we need to share real experiences. As of this writing my last hope will be eWallet, but I've yet to try it. I'd prefer to trust my data to an established company that's clicks AND mortar. But what I do know is this...

I've long experience with RoboForm and RoboForm2Go. Short of a heavy-duty, mightily-encrypted thing like IronKey, RoboForm works like a champ and does what it's supposed to do. Tech support is *passable* but sometimes you have to insist they properly answer your questions. RoboForm encrypts sensitive data behind good passwords and automates log-ins (behind as many or as few master passwords as you like). It's one flaw is that the titles of its Passcards and SafeNotes can be read, deleted and/or copied while RoboForm is logged-out. But in order to use them you'd have to un-encrypt and un-lock them and that's not likely to happen without your permission. So, for me, for accounts which have little money in them, the trade-offs are quite acceptable.

BUT, now I've got a new iPhone and need an app which performs with RoboForm's ease and also syncs to my PC desktop. SplashID isn't the one; I've tried it and found both the application and tech support lacking. When I tried to create automatic log-ins for two test accounts in SplashID, BOTH log-ins wouldn't launch automatically. SplashData's tech support explained that, "was a problem with the Web page," whereas RoboForm simply launches and logs-in easily and nearly effortlessly. SplashIDs tech support also had to be nudged, heavily, to explain what was or wasn't happening with their software. My experience of SplashID was it's Mediocreware.

So, I'm still looking. BUT, I won't be up-loading my sensitive log-in credentials to RoboForm Online's servers so I can access them from my iPhone. That's bloody nuts - anyone who'd ask you to do that has a heavily-inflated false sense of security. The first issue is that you'd have to trust RoboForm with your data. No, I don't on their server. Think of all the recent and legendary hacks into financial systems like banks. Look at sites like SecurityMetrics.com for a glimpse of news about this. And RoboForm's security couldn't be as strong as a bank's. If I was a hacker, I'd say RoboForm's Online servers would be an excellent target for some big-money thefts.

Answer (score 0):

On the mac the leader is 1 Password, it can easily by synced with your iPhone:

http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/a/1Password

Comment: I knew that, but I don't have a mac (yet?)... ;)

Comment: They have a windows beta now... http://support.agilewebsolutions.com/forumdisplay.php?86-Support-for-BETA

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to go on with [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) and its free.

Answer (score 0):

I think Roboform is the best password manager, and Roboform has released a Free Roboform App on Apple Store.

[Roboform Password Manager](http://system-tool.blogspot.com/2010/02/best-password-manager.html)

Answer (score 0):

[KeePass](http://keepass.info/) should be a safe choice. It is an open source app with multiplatform ports.
Password file import support is excellent. Available export formats are limited, but as long as the application works in every platform you need, this shouldn't be a problem.

Nevertheless, KeePass iPhone support has been very limited.
I have used [MyKeePass](http://mykeepass.wikidot.com/) since it was released early in 2010. Usability is not that great, because you have to type your master password every time you open the password file. Even with iPhone OS4 multitasking, this practically means EVERY time you'll need a password.
MyKeePass was out of the App Store for a while, but iPhone OS4 compatible version has been released now. 
There is also [iKeePass](http://ikeepass.de/), but it is only available in the U.S. App Store.

I think that multiplatform support and migration options are the most important features in a password manager. It is extremely painful to manually migrate lots of entries. Before, I used to have a Nokia Symbian phone with a synchronizable password manager (Handy Safe 5.0).
It actually worked better than KeePass + iPhone, had a decent two-way sync through USB for example. 
But, Handy Safe 5.0 didn't have any export formats and no other password manager imported Handy Safe files.
(KeePass added [Handy Safe 5.12](http://keepass.info/news/n100305_2.10.html) file support later, though.)